# Loop through a MySQL database until there is a result, then break

Tags: php, mysql, sql

If you look at the `else` part, there is a code comment that contains a question. How to repeat it, maybe with a different kind of loop? Unfortunately, I do not know how.

```
for ($id = 0; $id <= 16; $id++) {
    $count1++;
    $count2++;
    $sql = "SELECT a FROM jedynki where id = $count1 && f = '0' ";  
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $a = $row['a'];
            $a=substr($a,0,55);
            // do something...
            break;
        }
    } else {
        /*  If no results:
              1. Go back to the top of sql query
              2. Increment $count1
              3. Try again
            Repeat these steps (very important), until there is a result.  */
    }
    $sql = " SELECT a FROM jedynki where id = $count2 && f = '1' ";                  
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
             $b = $row['a'];
             $b=substr($b,0,55);
    ?>
        // do something...
    <?php
        }
      }           
    }
```

Comment: what are you trying to ? are you trying to fetch data?

Comment: actually else not required because data will be there or not loop will continue

Comment: yes , and output it, but in this for loop there is one more sql query and I need to output the result from second one always  after first one, then for loop can run again.

Comment: Yes I know, but I cannot put the rest of code here(says it is too long), and there is second query that can be executed only if the first one did.

Comment: I tried to put it together but the first one just overrides the second one.

Comment: Post all your code, we need to see it. Cut any unnecessary parts.

Comment: So I posted the rest. Then I need it like this: output result1 / then result 2. Again result1 / then result 2. If first query is empty ,then repeat it with count1+1. Do it to the point the query is true and then do the query number 2. AND do not try to do second query till the first one is done. I tried to put second one in first if loop but then it doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't been able to test it but it should work as far as I can tell. It increments `count1` as long as the result is null (the loop hasn't started yet) or the number of rows that were fetched is zero and queries the database with the new incremented value of `count1`.

```
for ($id = 0; $id <= 16; $id++) {
    $result = NULL;

    do {
        $count1++;
        $sql = "SELECT a FROM jedynki where id = $count1 && f = '0' ";  
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
    } while(($result == NULL) || ($result->num_rows == 0));

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        // do something...
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: So I posted the rest. Then I need it like this: output result1 / then result 2. Again result1 / then result 2. If first query is empty ,then repeat it with count1+1. Do it to the point the query is true and then do the query number 2. AND do not try to do second query till the first one is done. I tried to put second one in first if loop but then it doesn't work at all.

Comment: Oh shit it WORKED! Man thank you. I have one question more. I receive"execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in" . So probably it is because this loop doesnt want to break. Any idea how to do it ?

Comment: You could break the loop after it exceeded a certain amount of iterations to prevent infinite loops and errors such as the one you got.